# Dynamic memory allocation in 'c' Issues

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was writing a code using malloc for something and then faced a issue so i wrote a test code which actually sums up the whole confusion which is below::

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <error.h>

int main()     
{
     int *p = NULL;
     void *t = NULL;
     unsigned short *d = NULL;

     t = malloc(2);
     if(t == NULL) perror("\n ERROR:");
     printf("\nSHORT:%d\n",sizeof(short));
     d =t;
     (*d) = 65536;
     p = t; 
     *p = 65536;
     printf("\nP:%p: D:%p:\n",p,d);
     printf("\nVAL_P:%d ## VAL_D:%d\n",(*p),(*d));
     return 0;
  }
   Output:: abhi@ubuntu:~/Desktop/ad/A1/CC$ ./test

            SHORT:2
            P:0x9512008: D:0x9512008:
            VAL_P:65536 ## VAL_D:0
```

I am allocating **2 bytes** of memory using malloc. Malloc which returns **a void * pointer is stored in a void* pointer 't'**.

Then after that 2 pointers are declared **p - integer type and d - of short type**. then i assigned t to both of them**(p =t and d=t)** *that means both d & p are pointing to same mem location on heap.*

on trying to save 65536(2^16) to (*d) i get warning that large int value is truncated which is as expected.
Now i again saved 65536(2^16) to (*p) which did not caused any warning.

*On printing both (*p) and (*d) i got different values (though each correct for there own defined pointer type).*

My question are:

1. Though i have allocated 2 bytes(i.e 16 bits) of heap mem using malloc how am i able to save 65536 in those two bytes(by using (*p) which is a pointer of integer type).??
   i have a feeling that the cause of this is automatic type converion of void* to int* pointer (in p =t) so is it that assigning t to p leads to access to memory regions outside of what is allocated through malloc . ??.
2. Even though all this is happening how the hell derefrencing the same memory region through (*p) and (*d) prints two different answers( though this can also be explained if what i am thinking the cause in question 1).

**Can somebody put some light on this, it will be really appreciated..and also if some one can  explain the reasons behind this..**

Many thanks

Comment: Malloc might be rounding the requested size up towards a certain multiplier. Don't know about *nix, but Windows likes to round it up to multiples of 8 bytes. If that is the case, you're writing outside the area you requested, but it happens to be within the safety margin, and therefore you're not corrupting anything else.

Comment: You have carefully abused the casting power to obtain undefined behavior. C gives you great power and flexibility to do *bad things*. You have to take the responsibility to ***not do them***.

Comment: @dmckee i know what i am doing should not be done but after stumbling on this i was curious to know the exact reasons behind it which i initially guessed was the fact that automatic type conversion to int * of a 2 byte allocated void* pointer leads to int* pointer access more memory then 2 bytes because on my machine int is of 4 bytes. Is this correct(my assumption)

Comment: Sure, and then the *real* fun begins. Read about Big- and Little-endianness. Then read about mixed-endian and be prepared to cringe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your second question first:

The explanation is the fact that an `int` is generally 4 bytes, and the most significant bytes may be stored in the first two positions.  A `short`, which is only 2 bytes, also stores its data in the first two positions.  Clearly, then, storing `65536` in an `int` and a `short`, but pointing at the same memory location, will cause the data to be stored offset by two bytes for the `int` in relation to the `short`, with the two least significant bytes of the `int` corresponding to the storage for the `short`.

Therefore, when the compiler prints `*d`, it interprets this as a `short` and looks at the area corresponding to storage for a `short`, which is not where the compiler previously stored the `65536` when `*p` was written.  Note that writing `*p = 65536;` overwrote the previous `*d = 65536;`, populating the two least significant bytes with `0`.

Regarding the first question: The compiler does *not* store the `65536` for `*p` within 2 bytes.  It simply goes outside the bounds of the memory you've allocated - which is likely to cause a bug at some point.

Comment: So the fact that automatic type conversion to int * of a 2 byte allocated void* pointer leads to int* pointer access more memory then 2 bytes because on my machine int is of 4 bytes. Is this correct(my assumption)

Comment: and thanks for the clear and crisp answer which explains everything :)

Comment: Conceptually, that's it.  I'd say that technically speaking, perhaps it's not the best wording to say "automatic type conversion" in your sentence, because nothing is actually being converted - it's just that the compiler is accessing the bytes in memory as though they are storing one type of data, as opposed to accessing them as though they're storing another type.

Comment: ohhh my bad .. once again thanks for the response and the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no protection at all for writing out of bounds of an allocation. Just don't do it, anything can happen. Here it seems to work for you because by some coincidence the space behind the two bytes you allocated isn't used for something else.

Comment: Or at least he hasn't done anything that demonstrates some other use for that memory. The silence response to this kind of error is what lets them sneak up on you.

Answer (score 0):

1) The granularity of the OS memory manager is 4K.  An ovewrite by one bit is unlikely to trigger an AV/segfault, but will it corrupt any data in the adjacent location, leading to:

2) Undefined behaviour.  This set of behaviour includes 'aparrently correct operation', (for now!).