# How can one address can store more than one value?

Tags: c, pointers

Question is given in title:
I dont know why is this happening.
Can someone tell me how such tricks works.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a = 320;
    char *ptr;
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    ptr =( char *)&a;
    printf("%p\n",ptr);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7fffc068708c 
0x7fffc068708c
320
64
```

Comment: Check this question. Has a nice explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262217/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-issues

Answer (score 6):

There is only one value stored.

The second printf takes the first `char`'s worth of data at that address, promotes it to `int`, and prints the result. The first prints the whole `int`.

(`320 == 256 + 64`, or `0x140 == 0x01 0x40`)

Answer (score 5):

The actual data at `0x7fffc068708c` is `0x00000140`.

That's 320 in decimal.

But if you access it via `ptr =( char *)&a;`, then you only get `0x40`.

That's 64 in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, really: using a `char` pointer, you get rid of any extra bit of data above a byte:

```
  a = 320

 0x  00  00  00  00  01  40
    |      a               |   -> 0x 00000140 = 320
                       |ptr|   -> 0x 40       = 64
```

You "see" two values because you don't use all the precision available to you.

You would have "seen" one value if you had used a short instead of a char, but really, it's just *how* you interpret the data.

Answer (score 0):

The point is while assingning a to ptr you saying it is a pointer to a character and not a integer. Change that and try